# Formatting of folds

Tags: vimrc

Is it possible to 'fold at the proper indentation' ? For example, the point in the below is to see conditional flow:

[image]

However, with how the above is formatted, it's almost impossible to see visually that those 42 lines are part of the `else` statement. Is it possible to do something like this in vim, or not really?

Comment: The `foldtext` option controls how close folds are displayed, however I don't know if it can respect the indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible indeed!

As @Biggybi mentioned, you have to use `foldtext` to achieve that.

You assign a function to `foldtext`, and within this function, you can access the `v:foldstart` and `v:foldend` variables.

From there, you can access the indentation. Here's a simple example:

```
    function! NeatFoldText()
        let lines_count      = v:foldend - v:foldstart + 1
        return repeat(' ', indent(nextnonblank(v:foldstart))) . lines_count . ' lines '
    endfunction

    set foldtext=NeatFoldText()
```

---

If you want to have something a bit more advanced, here's what I have in my vimrc:

```
    function! NeatFoldText()
        let foldchar         = matchstr(&fillchars, 'fold:\zs.')
        let lines_count      = v:foldend - v:foldstart + 1
        let lines_count_text = printf("┈─ %1s lines ─┈", lines_count) . repeat(foldchar, 10)
        let foldtextstart    = repeat(' ', indent(nextnonblank(v:foldstart))) . " ••• " 
        let foldtextend      = lines_count_text . repeat(foldchar, 8)
        let foldtextlength   = strlen(substitute(foldtextstart . foldtextend, '.', 'x', 'g')) + &foldcolumn

        return foldtextstart . repeat(foldchar, winwidth(0) - foldtextlength) . foldtextend
    endfunction
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: that is really cool! It took me a bit of time to wrap my head around how vim does folding (TextMate, VS Code, etc. tend to found the top line (`while...`) and show that line with all the code folded under it, but here it basically requires you keep the top line but then do the folding on the level under that. Thanks!

Comment: is there any way to do it like this? https://imgur.com/a/6PO6umi

Comment: That's unfortunately not possible, you cannot keep the syntax coloring in a folded line. It is possible to do it but with no colors